# How to make my GAE system secure

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm developing an iOS app that used GAE as a backend. The only sensitive data my app will transfer to GAE is login details, anything else that is transferred is not sensitive. I intend to use SSL for everything, just coz that seems most sensible to me - is there any reason not to? Also, I want some way of ensuring that my app is the only way that my GAE system can be accessed (ie nobody accessing it from the web/spoofing a client to look like mine) how do I go about this? I read something about public and private keys but wasn't exactly sure if it was relevant?

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for your last question: you cant. There is no way you can enforce that your application is only accessed through your IOS app.
You can make it as hard as possible, but you cant guarantee that. The correct way is not relying on your IOS application
to validate the data send, but to do this verification in your gae app (if needed: **again**).
SSL is a good thing anyway - if done correctly (see: http://www2.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/files/android/p50-fahl.pdf )
But if the only sensitive data send is a password, you could consider using something like SRP ( start reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol )